# Concatenate same string x times

Tags: python, string-concatenation

There's a shortand way to concatenate a string x times instead of using something like this?

```
z = 'val'
y = ''
for x in range(1,10):
    y += z
```

Comment: how about `z * 10`?

Comment: Yes thanks for the response, wasn't aware that `*` operator works also for strings (since I'm new to Python). I didn't search for "repeat itself" since the technical term is another one, concatenation as I know. Thanks for the random downvotes to all.

Comment: Defining '*' (by a number) as repeat is an extension of the idea of defining '+' as concatenate.  It works for lists and tuples as well as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python you can just multiply the string to do this.

```
>>> mystr = 'nick'
>>> mystr*10
'nicknicknicknicknicknicknicknicknicknick'
```